# Work Stealing: join a recursive task requires stealing?

Tags: fork-join, work-stealing

I'm trying to understand the effect of work stealing on recursive tasks:
One of the advantages of work stealing is that the current worker/thread is  likely to execute its own spawned tasks; increasing data locality.
However, what happens in the common case when a worker join on its spawned tasks?
For example:

```
Future<String> a=pool.submit(()->doA());
b=doB();
return a.get()+b;
```

I think here the current thread will get blocked, thus unable to take the work from its own queue, thus another worker will have to steal those works. This would deny the locality advantage of work stealing. However, according to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing) 
"Work stealing is designed for a "strict" fork–join model of parallel computation"
I must have some mistake in my reasoning, but I can not found it.

More in the details, consider the following code:

```
Future<String> res=pool.submit(()->{
  Future<String> a=pool.submit(()->doA());
  b=doB();
  return a.get()+b;
  });
res.get();
```

This code should start the computation inside a worker. Such worker will spawn a new task. Then he try to get the result for this nested task. How is this nested task executed?

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure "how" to try, since the only think it should change is performance.
I have tried to print the current Thread name, and I can manage to get the "same" name and the same identity hashcode for the top level thread and the "a" one (using names of my example)
So, it seams like is working in the efficient way.. However, I do not understand how it can work. May be if a worker try to do get on a future that is not even started AND is on its own queue, then it will take it and execute it sequentially??

Comment: Without seeing all that you are doing, I can't say what. Now, the submitted work goes into a submission queue. Any thread can pick up that work. Usually, the submitting thread executes it's own work, but not always. That's why I need to see what you are doing.

Comment: I tried to make it more clear in the question! please consider my updated version.

Comment: I still have trouble following what you are doing since I cannot compile this. See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

The fork-join pool provides a high performance, parallel, fine-grined task execution framework for Java Programmers.

It solves the problem by divide and conquer. Splitiing the task into sub-tasks. A task creates a sub-task by *fork()* method.

When task client submits/invokes/executes a fork join task, the task gets into a *shared queue*, this shared queue is used to feed ***unshared double ended queue*** (aka "***deque***") managed by the ***WorkerThread***.

One or more ***WorkerThreads*** are called a Fork-Join pool.

A ***WorkerThread*** pulls off the task from the *shared queue*, and they go a head and process the work (using the unshared queue).

Each ***WorkerThread*** (which is actually a **Java thread**) in Fork-Join-Pool runs in a loop that continually scans for (sub-)task to execute.

The goal is to try to keep the ***WorkerThreads*** as busy as possible so we want them to always have something to do.

The goal is maximize processor core utilization.

Each ***WorkerThread*** has it's, **double ended queue** (aka "***deque***")  that serves as its main source of task.

Above and beyond, that other *shared queue* that used to get, non-fork join task into the fork-join pool, in 1st place.

The "***deque***" are implemented by *WorkQueue* (which is a Java class that's nested inside ForkJoinPool). Some important methods in that class are *push(), pop() and poll()*.

At some point, the task can't make any progress, since it's wait for the sub-task to complete by the *join()* method .

This join is different from a join in a Java thread.

In **Java Thread Join** if a task doesn't return a result, is blocks, and waits to this other thread to finish.

If in Fork-Join the *join()* happens to block, then the ***WorkerThread*** stops working on the current thread and start executing the sub-task..

Whenever you are calling a ***fork()*** inside compute method inside of a *RecursiveTask<>* or  *RecursiveAction*  that is always running in the context of thread in the fork-join-pool.

If a task a *RecursiveTask<>* or  *RecursiveAction* is running by the ***WorkerThread*** calls *fork()*, that new *ForkJoinTask** is pushed onto the head of that workers "***deque***" thread.

It pushes it, in **LIFO** order, Last In First Out.

When we call *join()* for this task, that task would be poped from the head of the "***deque***" (top of the stack)  and is run to completion(keep running till it's done) in the ***WorkerThread***.

Why do we do **LIFO**? Why do we push at the front and pop at the front ? In order to improve locality of reference, improve cache performance, so that you get the processing as quickly as possible, sometimes called fresh work before stale.

The ForkJoinTask enables fine-grained data parallelism.

A **ForkJoinTask** is lighter than a **Java thread**, it doesn't have it's own runtime stack .

A **ForkJoinTask** associates a chunk of data along with a computation on that data.

A real Java thread has it's own stack, registers, a lot of other resources that allow it to be scheduled independently managed by the thread scheduler, that the operating system has internally.

A large number of  **ForkJoinTask** can run in a much smaller number of **WorkerThreads** in the Fork-Join-Pool.

The number of **WorkerThreads** is typically (if not specified) a function of the number of cores. Each **WorkerThread** is a **Java thread** object with all it's accoutrements that you expect from a normal thread.

A **ForkJoinTask** has two important methods that control parrallel processing and merging the results, these are *fork()* and *join()*.

A *fork()* arranges to asynchronously execute this task in the appropriate thread pool. A *fork()* is like a lightversion of Thread.start().

A *fork()* doesn't create a Java worker thread (at least not directly), But eventually, it will run on a Java Thread.

It doesn't start to run immediately but instead it places the sub-Task on the head of the work queue.

A *join()* returns of the computation when the sub-Task is finished.
Join in a Fork-Join pool is different from the classic Java thread join.
Java thread is used as a barrier syncronizer to wait for another thread to finish and then you join with it (You can't proceed until the other one is done).

A join in a regular thread blocks the calling thread.

The join in a Fork-Join pool doesn't simply block the calling thread, instead, the **WorkerThread** is assigned to run the pending sub-tasks.

When the **WorkerThread** encounteres a *join()* it processes any other sub-tasks until it notices the target sub-task is done.  The **WorkerThreads** doesn't return to the caller until this sub-tasks results are finished.

A Join in a fork-join task is not block, it holds the current task, so the computation to be continued only after it's sub-tasks created by the *join()* finished.

The **WorkerThread** figures out, that the task is blocked till the sub-task is finished so it start to work on the sub-task.

A **WorkerThread** processes it's own "deque" in a **LIFO** order, by popping  (sub-)tasks from it's own "***deque***".

***WORK STEALING***
When a **WorkerThread** doesn't have anything else to do - "idle" .If **WorkerThread**'s own queue is empty, it will go and try to "steal" a sub-task from the tail of some other busy thread "***deque***", that is selected randomlly, inorder to maximaize core utilization.

The tasks are "stolen" in **FIFO** order, since an older stolen task may provide a large unit of work.

*Push()* and  *pop()* are only called by the owning worker thread  (To the top of the "***deque***") that is the reason they are most efficient they use wait-free "**C**ompare-**A**nd-**S**wap" **CAS** operations. **CAS** is a hardware level of atomically check and set the value of lock in memory – it never blocks . *push()* and *pop()* has a very lightweight locking.

*Poll()* may be called from another thread to "steal" as sub-task. When we call *poll()* that's because the other thread has been randomly assigned to try to "steal" sub-task from the end of this deque in **FIFO** order. *Poll()* is initiated by another thread, as a result it may not always be wait-free, so sometimes it has to "yield" and come back and try later again. "stealing" is fast but it may not be as fast as pushing and popping.